# jQuery horizontal and vertical positioning script not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Heres the design**
http://vvcap.net/db/OuxLOYioWmjIAavL5N9U.htp

**Here's a demo!**
http://designobvio.us/GoldGrid2/

I'm trying to get a vertically and horizontally jQuery script to run on IE8:

**Script Code**

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

     $(window).resize(function(){

      $('.padder').css({
       position:'absolute',
       left: ($(window).width() 
         - $('.padder').outerWidth())/2,
       top: ($(window).height() 
         - $('.padder').outerHeight())/2
      });

     });

     // To initially run the function:
     $(window).resize();

    });

</script>
```

Any ideas on why this script isnt working in IE8?

Comment: Your side question should really be another question... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to declare the heights and widths as numbers so you are certain the math can work properly, also since you are changing the CSS the value needs to be a string that includes 'px'

```
left: ((Number($(window).width()) - Number($('.padder').outerWidth()))/2)+'px',
top: ((Number($(window).height()) - Number($('.padder').outerHeight()))/2)+'px'
```

Something along those lines, I would probably set the values before the CSS.

```
var leftVal = Number($(window).width()) - Number($('.padder').outerWidth())/2;
var topVal = Number($(window).height()) - Number($('.padder').outerHeight()))/2;
```

Then:

```
left: leftVal+'px',
top: topVal+'px'
```

Full function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    var leftVal = Number($(window).width()) - Number($('.padder').outerWidth())/2;
    var topVal = Number($(window).height()) - Number($('.padder').outerHeight()))/2;

    $('.padder').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: leftVal+'px',
        top: topVal+'px'
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry i took this script from somewhere else.  my jquery skills are terrible.  where it says number should i declare a real number? I put in that code and it errored out?  If i do declare a number what should it be?

Comment: I made a change up there that might help. I think it is actually the second thing, because you are changing the top and left position in the CSS you have to include 'px' after the value. So for example "120px" rather than just "120"

Comment: NUmber() is a javascript function that will convert an object into a number, you can theoretcially have a string that is "555" but doing Math on that string may or may not work, I honestly don't know, anytime I do math I try to change the string I am working with into an official javascript Number.

Comment: Man this code is so much cleaner and it makes so much more sense this way. Unfortunatly it's just not working ; ; http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/3.html heres where I got the jQuery.  I also have updated the code http://www.designobvio.us/GoldGrid2/